# How to do rolling subtraction repeatedly with Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to do rolling subtraction repeatedly with a Pandas Dataframe?

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
value
100
1
4
10
5
3
```

I want to repeatedly subtract previous value with current value. I want the following output:

```
100
99
95
85
80
77
```

How can I do this? If I have multiple columns in the dataframe, how can I apply the same operation to all of the columns?

Answer (score 3):

A vectorized solution:

```py
-(df['value']).cumsum() + df['value'].iat[0]*2
```

Output:

```py
0    100
1     99
2     95
3     85
4     80
5     77
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine `expanding` with `np.subtract.reduce`:

```py
df.value.expanding(1).agg(np.subtract.reduce)

0    100.0
1     99.0
2     95.0
3     85.0
4     80.0
5     77.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Cool! Very short and concise. What do you think about mine? Any opinions?